# Merging cycles in undirected graph to create a tree

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Problem: Given an undirected graph with cycles, merge the minimal number of nodes to eliminate the cycles.

For example, the solution for the following graph:

```
     G      H
    / \    / \
A--B---C--D---E--F
    \ /        \
     I          J
```

would be

```
A--BCGI--DEH--F
           \
            J
```

I have a rough idea about how to solve this by doing a breadth-first search and merging the nodes towards the root whenever a cycle is detected, but it seems a bit complicated. I wonder if there's a well-known algorithm for the problem.

BTW: This is not a homework. :)

Comment: Why do you need to merge BCGI? Isn't it enough to merge B and C?

Comment: It isn't, since then there would be a multi-edge, and thus a cycle, between BC and G. (Deleted my previous comments, which only made things more confusing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a spanning tree using BFS or DFS
2. For every edge that's not in the tree, merge the edge's two nodes and all the nodes on the paths up to their nearest common ancestor.

That sounds pretty much like what you already thought of :).  It's a lot easier, though, if you use a union-find data structure to keep track of the merging instead of actually modifying the graph as you go.  See http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Union_Find

Comment: Thanks a lot, Matt. That helps.