# Find all vertices in a directed graph with paths to every other vertex in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, graph-theory

Is it possible to identify all vertices v in a directed graph G, such that there is a path from v to every other vertex in G, in O(n+m) time?  Naively, we could run BFS or DFS from every vertex in G to see if each vertex meets this requirement, but this would take time O(n * (n+m)).  Is there are a slicker way to do this, or is that not possible?

Comment: Just an idea. Find strongly connected components (linear time) and contract each of them to a single vertex. You get a DAG. If that DAG is a tree, all vertices in the corresponding strongly connected component are the answer. If not, there are no such vertices.

Comment: The standard Dijkstra algorithm will tell you whether or not every node in a graph is reachable from a particular node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations can be made here

1. If there are no cycles in the graph then there will be <= 1 such vertex.
2. If there are > 1 such vertices then they need to lie on a cycle.

Given a graph:-
[image]

If we [merge all the nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540318/merging-cycles-in-undirected-graph-to-create-a-tree) that are present in a cycle.
[image]

The resultant graph will be a tree with at most one node which can reach all other nodes.

From here we need to find that one node (which may comprise of multiple nodes).

Let me know if this makes sense, I'll try to update with some working code.

Comment: This definitely makes sense and thank you very much for your clear answer!  I have a quick follow-up question, which might be trivial: in your last step, how do we find that final node (which may be multiple nodes) in linear time or O(n+m) time?

Comment: Loop over all the vertices and do a DFS/BFS from each node. Mark every visited node. There will be only one node, after running bfs/dfs from which there won't be any unmarked nodes left. That one will be the node we want.

Comment: @Daniel can you accept this answer if it served the scenario?